Equivalent Resistance across terminals "in the middle" of a circuit
I'm trying to find the equivalent resistance across terminals A-B.
I have a huge issue with problems where the terminals are "in the middle" of the circuit.
I bet there's a clever way to rearrange the resistors to make it obvious but I just can't see it.
I'm posting one of my many attempts, where I tried redrawing the circuit and got to a Y-Δ transform but that didn't lead me anywhere.
Could you please explain step-by-step how to combine the resistors?


It does not matter where the terminals are drawn. You can slide them over to right and then they are not in the middle of a circuit. As long as the terminals connect to same nodes.

Since you discussed redrawing, here's an equivalent:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In this case, I just set B to ground (or \$0\:\text{V}\$.)
You can now easily see which parts are in series and in parallel.
Hopefully, that helps. If not and you expand a little, I'll try and move the ball a little more down the field for you.

The way you redrew the circuit is fantastic. I understand what you did but I'd struggle to do it on my own.
Would you be so kind as to do another one for me?
This one is much simpler:
Circuit1

@user486392 The main thing is to pick a ground (you can pick any one wire/node) and then just start removing any wires you can live without. In your new example case, set B to ground (or A) and erase lots of wires. You should be able to see the steps here. Just practice. It won't take long and things will get much much easier. See also a very nice discussion here by jonk. For more complex circuits you will need to recognize "functional sections." That takes a little more time to acquire.

Here are the first very basic simplifications you can make: -

So, R1 and R3 are in series and together, that series combination is in parallel (||) with R5. Then R2 and R4 are in parallel.
Once it is redrawn as I have done above, you can clearly see that the two modified resistors are in series and form a single resistor with new value of (R1 + R3)||R5 + R4||R2.
That new resistor is in parallel with R6. Can you take it from here?

You are sloppy with your series/parallel math. You should use + for series and || for parallel.
(R1 + R3) || R5
You missed: R2 || R4
No Delta-Y transformations are needed.
